# Flutter - Stop FutureBuilder operation in between process

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I cancel `FutureBuilder` operation when rebuilding the widget

Lets say I have a code like this... Every time i pressed the Floating button the widget rebuilds calling `myFuture` which waits five seconds and then the counter increments... Now I want that during that five seconds if I pressed the Floating button the current Future (which is still is delayed) should **stop its operation** and the new Future will be called...So at the end I should get a counter of 2 but instead I get 3...

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var counter = 0;
  
  myFuture()async{
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:5));
    counter++;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: myFuture(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          else return Text(counter.toString());
        }
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: ()=>setState(() {}),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to cancel a Future, you can use the `CancelableOperation` from the `async` package.

It's implementation would look like the following :

```
  Future<dynamic> executeCancelable(Future<dynamic> futureMethod) async {
    operation?.cancel();
    operation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(futureMethod, onCancel: () {
      print('Future stopped');
    });

    return operation.value;
  }

  Future<dynamic> futureMethod() async {
    return Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {
      return counter++;
    });
  }
```

Which can be called with the following method :

```
executeCancelable(futureMethod())
```

**Note that in this example, I'm using a Future.delayed wich can't "really" be cancelled as [explained here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37817).**
This snippet would work well with an API query for example.

Comment: There is no general mechanism to cancel a `Future`; that is not specific to `Future.delayed`.  At best you can set a flag and make the `Future` computation check it to exit early.  All `CancelableOperation` does is to prevent completion callbacks from being triggered; it does not stop the `Future`'s computation itself from executing.

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;

  fiveSeconds() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  
  }

    twoSeconds() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    
  }

   bool _futureTime = true; 

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _futureTime ? fiveSeconds() : twoSeconds(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          else counter++;
     return Text(counter.toString());
        }
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){setState(() {
       _futureTime = !_futureTime;
        });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My code have nothing to do with the counter.. It was just an example... I want is.. to cancel the future function which is still being run when `setstate` is called

Comment: I edited my answer, move your logic outside the Future.dalyed, and run it in the future builder, i.e `counter++`. It will work.

Comment: Lets say i have 3 `FutureDelayed` in my function .. and after each FutureDelay it does something... So if its on the 2nd delay and i pressed the floating button.... the third delay should not run at all....

Comment: @thenoobslayer Do you mean, if you've say 3 futures (all delaying for 5s), when future1 is running and you press FAB, it should cancel future1 and run future2 and if again FAB is pressed, future2 should be cancelled and future3 should run and do the operation after 5s?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a `Stream` and `StreamBuilder` instead of `Future` and `FutureBuilder` if that fits your use case.

```
void main() {
  // keep a reference to your stream subscription
  StreamSubscription<List> dataSub;
  
  // convert the Future returned by getData() into a Stream
  dataSub = getData().asStream().listen((List data) {
    updateDisplay(data);
  });

  // user navigated away!
  dataSub.cancel();
}
```

source: https://dart.academy/how_cancel_future/