# Terminate a function in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-future

I have a function witch returns a Future.

```
main(){
function().timeout(Duration(milliseconds: 100), onTimeout: () {
        print("exit function");
      });
}

Future<void>function()async{
  await Future.delay(Duration(milliseconds: 500);
  print("function was run");
  return Future.value(null);
}
```

I want to exit the function after the timeout.
In the example above i expect the output `exit function`.

How ever, the output from the flutter console is:

```
exit function
function was run
```

Does anybody know how to generete my expected result?

- function can be of any type.

Thanks for ur help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67012599/flutter-stop-futurebuilder-operation-in-between-process

Comment: You cannot cancel a `Future`.  At best you can set a flag and have your `Future`'s computation check it to exit early.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to cancel a Future function. As alternative, you may consider using Streams if it fits your use case. You can subscribe to a StreamSubscription and call `cancel()` if needed to. Here's a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17603920) provided in a post.